# React Native : How to change bottom tabs behaviour

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want that when I click on the last bottom tab, it makes appears a modal on screen, but it does not work

```
function MyTabs() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(true);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Mon compte" component={AccountScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Mes transferts" component={TransfertsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Créer" component={CreerScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Suivi" component={SuiviScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="More" component={MoreScreen} listeners={({ navigation, route }) => ({
                tabPress: e => {
                    console.log(1)
                    e.preventDefault();
                    <Modal isVisible={modal}>
                      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <Text>I am the modal content!</Text>
                        <Button title="Fermer la modale" onPress={() => {setModal(false);}}></Button>
                      </View>
                    </Modal>
                },
            })} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

How to make it work ?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the problem statement. Looking at the code, I'd guess you want something to **disappear** on click maybe? Also the JSX is all over the place, there tab press handler / callback should not have any JSX inside of it.

Comment: No, I want to display a Modal by clicking the last tab, without changing page (just display the popup when I click the last tab)

Comment: Please rewrite the problem statement. 2 short paragraphs would be good :)

Comment: P.S. ultimately the problem is that you cannot have `e => { <JSX/> }`. Code needs to be structured a bit differently.